# Piping periodic data between Python scripts

Tags: pipe, python, tail

> [How to receive data from the environment e.g. bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725827/how-to-receive-data-from-the-environment-e-g-bash)

I am trying to launch two Python scripts in `bash` and pipe `stdout` from one of them to `stdin` of the other. The first script outputs a single number every second.

```
./script1 | ./script2
./script1 > ~/file &; tail -f ~/file
```

I tried those, but can't get it working. `script1` outputs via Python's `print`, while script2 is tested with `echo "21.11 22.23 33.233" | ./script2` and is known to work.

If I terminate `script1` ofter some time, and then `cat ~/file`, I see the actual data. However, at the time of execution, neither of the above examples work.

How do I make this work? I would like to be able to work both with and without intermediate file.

Comment: you have to flush the output buffer

Answer (score 2):

In the python script make sure you call:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

after `print`-ing. You don't have to do that on each statement, but you have to do it on each group of `print`s that has to be processed. ( `import sys` if not done yet).

Comment: Why is that. In the question that I linked to, it is discussed if there is a better way to output data than `print`. So is there (it's only one print per iteration)?

Comment: That question is about reading data from stdin, not printing (which writing to sys.stdout)

Comment: `Secondly, is print i a proper way to stream data to the environment?`